# group by and aggregate in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
    code_presentation   code_module score   id_student  id_assessment   date_submitted
0   2013J               AAA         78.0    11391        1752           18
1   2013J               AAA         70.0    11391        1800           22
2   2013J               AAA         72.0    31604        1752           17
3   2013J               AAA         69.0    31604        1800           26
.....
```

I need to count submitted days and
How to groupby it right ti get a result such as :

```
id_student  id_assessment date_submitted
11391       1752          1
            1800          1
31604       1752          1
            1800          1
```

...
etc

I try:

```
analasys_grouped = analasys.groupby ( 'id_student', as_index = False)\
.agg({'id_assessment':'count', 'date_submitted': 'count'})
analasys_grouped
```

but it is not working right

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to apply [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on `id_assessment` grouped by `id_student`. Try:

```
assessment_count_per_student = df.groupby('id_student')['id_assessment'].value_counts()

print(assessment_count_per_student)

id_student  id_assessment
11391       1752             1
            1800             1
31604       1752             1
            1800             1
Name: id_assessment, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass `id_assessment` into the `groupby` statement.

```
df.groupby(['id_student', 'id_assessment'])['date_submitted'].count()


id_student  id_assessment
11391       1752             1
            1800             1
31604       1752             1
            1800             1
```

---

in your attempt, you're only grouping by `id_student` then counting the assesment and date submitted.